# Como faço pra tirar essas bolinhas?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Como posso fazer para tirar essas bolinhas?

http://prntscr.com/jr9vpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Removendo marcador de espaço

Atralho: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Caminho: **Edit**>**Advanced**>**View White Space**.

## Removendo Outlining(collapse)

Para remover o `Outlining` vá em **Tools**>**Options**>**Text Editor**>**XML**>**Miscellaneous** e desmarque a opção **Enter outlining mode when files open**

Depois basta fechar e abrir o arquivo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um atalho é pesquisar por *Outlining* na caixa de pesquisa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[fonte/documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178155(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Vai no ícone da engrenagem e clica Configurações e pesquisa por `renderWhitespace`.

e muda `editor.renderWhitespace: "all"` para `editor.renderWhitespace: "none"`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]